# Hibernate/JPA: Embeddable is initialized altough all properties are null or empty

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate and have the following JPA model:

```java
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

  @Embedded
  MyEmbeddable embedded;

}

@Embeddable
public class MyEmbeddable {

    @Column    
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Size(min = 1)
    private Set<MyEnum> usage;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDate localDate;

}
```

MyEntity *can* contain MyEmbeddable, but the whole embeddable should be optional. So I would prefer that `MyEntity.embedded` is `null` when all properties of `MyEmbeddable` are empty or null.

However, when I'm reading such an entity from DB, Hibernate initializes `embedded` as `non-null` - which leads to constraint errors when the entity gets flushed to the database again.

As a workaround I would have to write some code to `null` the `embedded` property before flushing/persisting - which seems like a very bad idea to me.

I suspect that the ElementCollection causes this inizialitation behaviour - because according to JPA spec ElementCollections are always initialized `empty` (not null).

Any ideas/hint how you can tell Hibernate to not initialized `embedded` at all?

Comment: you define setter and add your logic there, check if object is not null and something like, `embedded.isValid()` and set embedded as null if it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all embedded column values are null? `localDate` is annotated with `NotNull`, so I think that's the issue preventing the embedded property from being null. Also, the `@Size(min = 1)` on the set looks like it can also be a problem too.

Note that Hibernate provides an option for controlling that behavior (https://in.relation.to/2016/02/10/hibernate-orm-510-final-release/):

> Historically Hibernate would always treat all null column values for an @Embeddable to mean that the @Embeddable should itself be null. 5.1 allows applications to dictate that Hibernate should instead use an empty @Embeddable instance. This is achieved via an opt-in setting: `hibernate.create_empty_composites.enabled`.
>
> See [HHH-7610](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7610) for details.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. As mentioned by @eidottermihi, the problem is that we want the whole structure to be optional. If it is there, though, we want proper validation at the contained fields. That's from a domain object and DB perspective.